How do i determine if SAF is required on a specific device?
I need to determine the Android version when an application was first installed.
I know that Storage Access Framework is required for Android 11* (API  30) and later but that requirement is based on the Android version when the app was installed.
How do I determine at what Android version my app was first installed, or if SAF is forced?
Where do I find this info?
I'm assuming it is somewhere in GetPackageManager().
The reason is in Android 11 and later you cannot access databases in external storage.
I have enabled SAF in most everything else.

Android 10 if you enable legacy storage.


"that requirement is based on the Android version when the app was installed" -- how did you come to that conclusion?

I can't find the best description but this comment on GitHub gives you an idea. I am using preserveLegacyExternalStorage.
Note: If you set preserveLegacyExternalStorage to true, the legacy
storage model remains in effect only until the user uninstalls your
app.

A comment on Medium:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-11-storage-faq-78cefea52b7c
preserveLegacyExternalStorage flag allows an app to retain legacy storage access on upgrades even while targeting Android 11. However beware that on new installs on Android 11, this flag has no effect.

I forgot about preserveLegacyExternalStorage, sorry!

I may have found an answer. I will have to test it tomorrow...  "In a library, you do not control whether the app is in normal or legacy mode. If you need different code for those two cases, you can call Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy(), which will return true if the app is in legacy mode, false otherwise."

Using Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy() does what I need. I tested it on Android 10 with request/preserveLegacyExternalStorage and without. Without, you cannot access databases outside of app specific storage and SAF is required to access documents outside of the app.
